# При использовании AxAcroPDF на части машин AccessViolationException - C#

Tags: c#, acrobat

Вылетает при открытии формы с AxAcroPDF на части машин с AccessViolationException, на остальных работает нормально.
ОС Windows 7, Framework 4.0. Приложение - Winforms. Стоит AcrobatReader XI

Понятно, что при открытии формы с AxAcroPDF на что-то прав не хватает, но не могу понять даже от чего оттолкнуться

Стектрейс: (видно, что падает на инициализации компонента)

```
Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException 
Stack: at 

System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods+IO|eObject.DoVerb(Int32, IntPtr, IOleClientSite, Int32, IntPtr, COMRECT) at       
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.DoVerb(Int32) at 
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InPlaceActivateO at 
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32) at 
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHand|eO at 
System.Windows.Form5.Control.CreateControI(Boolean) at 
System.Window5.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boo|ean) at 
System.Windows.Forms.Contro|.CreateControl(Boo|ean) at 
System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInitO at 
CreatePackage.CreateJnitializeCornponentO at 
CreatePackage.Create..ctor0 at 
CreatePackaqe.Form1.createDocumentButton Click(Svstem.Obiect. Svstem.EventAras}
```

Comment: Добавляйте логирование и смотрите логи. Показывайте код, на какой конкретно строчке падает, показывайте стектрейс.

Comment: Можно оттолкнуться от того, что `AccessViolationException` это не про права доступа. Это исключение выбрасывается при попытке доступа в память по невалидному указателю и происходит это при взаимодействии с *неуправляемым* кодом.  Скорее всего, проблема в том, что вы неправильно работаете с вашей библиотекой `AxAcroPDF`. [Публикуйте код](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Не думаю, что происходит взаимодействие с неуправляемым кодом, т.к. всё, что делается - это просто размещается компонент на форме

Comment: Насчёт того, что неправильно работаю с библиотекой - тоже не уверен. Проблема есть только на небольшом проценте машин. На остальных машинах всё работает нормально. Думаю дело в самих машинах

Comment: Код - как такового нет, объект просто размещён на форме через визуальный конструктор

Comment: Стектрейс: (видно, что падает на инициализации компонента)

Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods+IO|eObject.DoVerb(Int32, IntPtr, IOleClientSite, Int32, IntPtr, COMRECT)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.DoVerb(Int32)

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InPlaceActivateO
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHand|eO
at System.Windows.Form5.Control.CreateControI(Boolean)
at System.Window5.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boo|ean)
at System.Windows.Forms.Contro|.CreateControl(Boo|ean)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInitO
at CreatePackage.CreateJnitializeCornponentO
at CreatePackage.Create..ctor0
at CreatePackaqe.Form1.createDocumentButton Click(Svstem.Obiect. Svstem.EventAras}

Comment: Погадаю. На тех машинах, где работает, пользователи сидят под админскими правами. Где не работает - под правами простых юзеров.

Comment: нет, права админские везде (это первое, что подумали :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло отключение защиты DEP.